# Swift NWConnection - Receive failed with error "No message available on STREAM"

Tags: swift, networking, tcp, stream

I'm currently working on an iOS-App and i need to connect to another device. The NWConnection is successfully established using TCP and I can receive one (and only one) message from the remote device and get an error immediately. The connection gets cancelled (caused by the error I guess).
The console log shows:

```
Hello World.
[connection] nw_flow_add_read_request [C1 <ip and port of remote device> ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] already delivered final read, cannot accept read requests
[connection] nw_read_request_report [C1] Receive failed with error "No message available on STREAM"
error
```

My code looks like this:

```swift
private func setupReceive() {
        NWCon!.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 65536) { (data, _, isComplete, error) in
            if let data = data, !data.isEmpty {
                let message = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                
                if(message!.contains("Hello World")) {
                    print("Hello World.")
                } else if(message == "Closing connection!") {
                    //...
                }
            }
            if error != nil { print("error: \(error)") }
            else { self.setupReceive() }
        }
    }
```

The remote device only sends one package and to receive further packages, the method gets called again.

EDIT: I printed the error message and got

```
error: Optional(POSIXErrorCode: No message available on STREAM)
```

which seems to refer to POSIXError ENODATA.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  Just ran into this myself

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: I just ran into the same error, but I'm unable to reproduce it. In my particular case, the 'cancelled' and 'default' states for NWConnection.State were unhandled, and I'm guessing that one of those "tripped" and I continued in my tight loop of reading off the socket repeatedly.